# Upgrading OSX/Xcode - linking failure

Tags: xcode, macos

ALL,

I started my project on OSX 10.8 with the Xcode 5.1 (latest available for that OSX). Everything was building and running fine and it still is. The project consist of a binary executable and couple of dylib sub-projects.

Recently I bought myself a new Mac laptop. I installed Xcode on it (version 9), pull my sources from git hub and tried to re-compile/run it.

After fixing some minor directories issuers for compilation (some header search path were wrong), I received a warning about -L directory not found. However linking succeeded.

Trying to run the program obviously failed because the dylib files were not at the place were Xcode would look for it.

Looking further I tried to see if there would be any differences on where both machines store the build results. I opened the "Xcode->Project Properties..." menu, but turns out that those settings are the same on both laptops.

Next I checked the "Fie->Project Properties..." on both machines, but those 2 are also turns out to be the same.

Now I'm at the loss - where else should I look? The old laptop build everything without warnings and the program executes successfully.

On the old laptop the subprojects are stored inside ~///build/Debug.

On the new laptop the folder ~///build does not exist.

Now I can create the directory manually and copy over the files, but the program is still under development and the code is changing.

Any pointers would be appreciated.

TIA!

P.S.: Sorry for the long post.

Comment: In `Build Phases` you probably need to copy the `dylib` into the application directory where it should be stored.

Comment: @l'L', shouldn't it be handled by the Xcode project?